# Do we have module positions in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, module

I wish to create content in Wordpress similar to content in position 1, position 2 and position 3 in Joomla.. This means i'll have three boxes with content next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress you have widgets instead of modules.

You can drag and drop them to sidebars from the backend.

Comment: Thanks. I still need to know if the sidebar and footer is the only place you can position the widgets? Can I position them in the body area?

Comment: It all depends on the template. There is also an extension that you can place widgets in pages and posts: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-wordpress-widgets-in-post-and-page-content/